# `.gitconfig` の形式は独自のものか、それとも汎用的なものか

Tags: git

`.gitconfig`の以下のようなデータ形式は`YAML`や`json`のようになにか汎用的な形式なのでしょうか？

それとも独自の形式なのでしょうか？

```
[user]
     email = foo@example.com
     name = ironsand
[core]
     autocrlf = false
[push]
     editor = vim
     default = simple
```

似たような形式は他にも見たことがありますが、形式の名前が決まっているなら知りたく質問いたしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git 自体のドキュメントを読む限り、何かのフォーマットを流用しているわけではなく、独自に定義しています。たとえば [v2.17.1 の config.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.17.1/Documentation/config.txt#L20) には Syntax の節があり、ここで文法が定義されています。

類似の文法を持つフォーマットとして [INI ファイル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB)や [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) がありますが、少なくとも形式上は何かのフォーマットを使うよう指定されているわけでは無いようです。

Answer (score 3):

標準化されたフォーマットではありませんが、広く使われている**INIファイル**ではないでしょうか。

```
; comment
[section]
name=value
```

[INIファイル - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB)

> INIファイルは構造の単純なテキストファイルであり、設定ファイルのフォーマットとしてよく使われている。
>   INIファイルという名前はこのファイルの一般的な拡張子「.INI」から来ている。
>   INIファイルのフォーマットは規格化・標準化はされておらず、明確には決まっていない。

Comment: INIファイルって標準化されてなかったんですね。回答ありがとうございます。